# C*-algebra generated by a non invertible normal element

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $x\in A$ be a non-invertible normal element. By functional calculus,  we know $$C^*(x,1)\simeq C(\sigma(x))$$ 
Where $\sigma(x)$ means the spectrum of $x$.

I need to construct non-unital C*-algebra generated by $x$ means $C^*(x)$. If $0$ is an accumulation point of $\sigma(x)$, then I think $C*(x)\simeq C_0(\sigma(x)/\{0\})$.

But If $0$ is an isolated point, for which subset of $\sigma(x)$, there is an isomorphism?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If $0$ is an isolated point, the only new thing is that $\sigma(x)\setminus\{0\}$ is still compact. So
$$
C_0(\sigma(x)\setminus\{0\})=C(\sigma(x)\setminus\{0\}).
$$

Comment: Sure, it's right. But I would like to characterize the $C^*(x)$. In other words, I want to know the character space of $C^*(x)$.

Comment: Like my answer says, when $0$ is an isolated point the character space of $C^*(x) $ is $\sigma (x)\setminus\{0\} $.

Comment: But in this case constant function 1 belongs to $C(\sigma(x))$, while $C^*(x)$ is not unital.

Comment: Why do you say so? Did you try an example? If $0$ is an isolated point of $\sigma (x) $, it is true that $1\not\in C^*(x) $; but $C^*(x) $ is still is unital.

Comment: If it's possible, give me an example of $C^*(x)$ that is still unital where $0$ is an isolated point of $\sigma(x)$.

Comment: $A=C^*(x)$, where $$x=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: If you want an infinite-dimensional version, take $f\in C(\{0\}\cup[1,2])$ where $f$ is the function given by $f(t)=t$. Then $C^*(f)=\{g\in C(\{0\}\cup[1,2]):\ g(0)=0\}\simeq C([1,2])$.